# SQL database manipulation - How do I append the parent name to the child name in this database example

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `SQL database`, I have access via the `SQL tab` in `phpmyadmin`.

I have parent and child data in the same `table`, I want to write a script to append the parent name to the end of the child name and update the `SQL database`, like in the example below.

This is what I currently have
[image: database before]

This is what I want
[image: database after]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Outer JOIN` with `CONCAT` and `coalesce` function.

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Type VARCHAR(50),
   ProductNumber INT,
   Name VARCHAR(50),
   Parent INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('paren', 125000,'Bike',NULL);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('child', 125001,'Small',125000);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('child', 125002,'Large',125000);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT c.Type,c.ProductNumber,coalesce(CONCAT(c.Name,' ',p.Name),c.Name) name,c.Parent  
FROM T p RIGHT JOIN T c
ON p.ProductNumber  = c.Parent
```

**[Results]**:

```
|  Type | ProductNumber |       name | Parent |
|-------|---------------|------------|--------|
| child |        125001 | Small Bike | 125000 |
| child |        125002 | Large Bike | 125000 |
| paren |        125000 |       Bike | (null) |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/393374/4)

**NOTE**

Why you need an `outer join` because you need to take `Parent.Name` by `child.Parent` and need to show Parent and child row.

1. An `outer join` returns a set of records that include what an inner join would return but also includes other rows for which no corresponding match is found in the other table.
2. [CONCAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) can combine multiple columns value be a string.
3. [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) returns the first non-null expression from multiple columns.

[Inner Join vs. Outer Join](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Inner_Join_vs_Outer_Join)

Comment: Perfect thanks - How would I then update the Name field with the new data?

Comment: Also can someone explain how the script above works? i'm trying to learn

Comment: Still can't figure out how to update the database with the results, sorry i'm new to this

Comment: The above SELECT query creates the data I need, but how do I write an UPDATE query to write that data to the database?

Comment: @darylh I add some explain for you

Answer (score 0):

Convert `SELECT` to `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE T c
LEFT JOIN T p ON p.ProductNumber = c.Parent
SET c.Name = COALESCE(CONCAT(c.Name, ' ' , p.Name), c.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to update you on the final code as it differs slightly from the above posts. I needed to add back in the `and c.Type = 'child'`

```
UPDATE T c
LEFT JOIN T p ON p.ProductNumber = c.Parent and c.Type = 'child'
SET c.Name = COALESCE(CONCAT(c.Name, ' ' , p.Name), c.Name)
```

Thanks for all your help.